# How can I connect to a Microsoft Access database using PHP?

Tags: php, database

I tried to connect to MS Access database using PHP PDO from my ubuntu webserver but couldn't. I got this error:

```
Connexion Access échouée : SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

My connection class is:

```
class GesEcoleService{
    var $dsn;
    var $user;
    var $password;
    var $dbh;

    public function Connect(){
        $this->dsn = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=/var/www/rep/bd/GesEcoles.mdb;Uid=';
        $this->user = '';
        $this->password = '';

    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connexion Access Ã©chouÃ©e  : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is PDO and PDO_ODBC active in PHP?

Comment: Stackoverflow seems to have a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841948/pdo-odbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this as well. I found that the syntax for MS Access has slightly changed:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$dbName;Uid=Admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP components are active in the system for using PDO and ODBC, than take a look to the following.

The correct syntax for connection is:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=$dbUser; Pwd=$dbPassword;");
```

Observe the difference, your code does not send the `Pwd=` part.

Comment: In this case, there isn't user and pasword to access to database